# Mathematical tripos part III at Cambridge University

Tags: soft-question, advice

I am currently pursuing a Bachelor+Master program in mathematics and physics. While the material is very interesting, I feel it sometimes is lacking in the mathematical rigour necessary for Phd studies in mathematics.

A while ago, I discovered the one-year Master program (part III of the tripos) in mathematics at Cambridge University, and it seemed to feature a lot of highly interesting material. I think it would be a nice complement to my current program, and I am very interested in taking the course.

My only concern is, that at the time of graduating from my current program, I will be 26 years old. Would this be much too old for taking the part III course, and also, would I, upon (hopefully) completing the course, be too old for pursuing a Phd at a good university?

Thanks!

Comment: No. 27 is not too late to start a PhD, and not much older than 26 if you skipped the Masters program anyway. Many people have made a contribution to mathematics after late starts. Besides, you are not wasting that year. During that one year masters you are still learning standard material, which is what you do when you start a PhD.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But would you say it's very late to start part III of the tripos at 26? Since the BA program is 3 years in UK and since most students begin their undergraduate studies at the age of 18, I guess most students who take the part III are 21. Do you happen to know if there are any "older" students taking the part III?

Comment: FWIW, when I took Part III, most of the students were 21--22, but certainly a nonzero number were older, some 30+. As long as you're prepared for the course, age shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh Thank you for your comment! How old would you say that some of the older students were?

Comment: Is the [mature student](http://www.study.cam.ac.uk/undergraduate/access/mature/) thing relevant in anyway?

Comment: @GitGud By the looks of it, the link is useful for when considering colleges to apply to, but I can't see much for the specific Faculty - it also seems to apply mainly for Undergraduate programs, and not grad ones. While age can sometimes be a factor when applying for the undergraduate BA program in Maths, I'm fairly sure that this isn't case for the Masters/Graduate programs.

Comment: @GitGud Thank you for your reply! I do not think the "mature student" thing is relevant if I already have a degree. The "affiliated student" was something I hadn't heard about before, but I guess it would only be relevant if I wanted to take the BA (which (hopefully) would not be necessary).

Comment: @AndrewD Agreed. However part III is part of their undergrad course, I believe.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Anyway, I wish you luck. You shoulkd also consider asking about this at [Academia S.E.](http://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @GitGud For the undergraduates, we can automatically go onto Part III if we get a first in Part II; otherwise we can appeal to the Graduate Board, and if the person has a high enough 2.1 and a few good words by their Director of Studies, they can also go onto Part III. While for us the Masters/Part III is indeed intergrated, we can only go onto it under certain conditions.

Comment: @AndrewD Interesting, thanks. What does 'high enough 2.1' mean?

Comment: @GitGud Thank you, and thank you for the link that you provided!

Comment: @GitGud It is the second-highest degree classification one can get in universities in England.

Comment: @GitGud Unfortunately the vagueness is because there is no well-defined cutoff (or at least of that I'm aware of). Certainly if you were the highest rank person with a $2.1$, then you could be allowed on, but even if you had a mid $2.1$ you could presumably continue on - I would assume the Graduate Board would look at the person's supervision reports and hear what their Director of Studies has to say; if a person was really talented but happened to have a nightmare during the exams, I doubt that would stop their progression onto Part III.

Comment: @ZhenLin [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_undergraduate_degree_classification#Upper_second-class_honours), got it. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrewD Seems like students there are constantly under huge pressure.

Comment: @AndrewD You _should_ be in the top 40%: see [here](http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/postgrad/mathiii/partiimeeting/), but it's not a hard rule.

Comment: @GitGud As a student there, your assertion is correct. While our first two terms aren't too stressful, the exam terms are probably best described as hell. And thanks Zhen Lin, I guess I now know what to aim for in my third year (for those curious, the top 40% corresponds to the top quarter of $2.1$'s and higher).

Comment: @AndrewD Can I invite you to a chat room? I'm curious about how stuff works there. Zhen Lin, OP and whoever else is interested in welcome.

Comment: @GitGud Sure (adding more characters...)

Comment: An additional question: My university uses a grading system 1-5, where 5 is the highest and usually corresponds to 80%+ on exams. Because this grading system does not contain anything equivalent of the usual 'A', do you think it will be difficult to convert the grades in a satisfactory way?

Comment: Guys, try to join the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10524/a-d-g-g-j-f-s-and-z-l).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I assume the University would get in contact with your University to get specific details.

Comment: @AndrewD Alright, I guess that makes sense.

Comment: I've been following your discussion in the chat room. Unfortunately I could not join due to a lack of rep, but I still got some useful info. Thanks! I have to log off now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally, I would suggest emailing the relevant part of the University's Faculty of Mathematics, where you can find contact information on the bottom of the this page: http://www.maths.cam.ac.uk/postgrad/mathiii/.

I don't know how much you know about how the University of Cambridge operates, but if you were to apply for the one-year Masters, you would also need to look at the different colleges at Cambridge (there's more information available here: http://www.admin.cam.ac.uk/students/gradadmissions/prospec/studying/colleges/index.html). The University also has open days (both generally and faculty specific) throughout the year, so it may be worth having a look to see when they are.

On a more personal note, I doubt your age would be a barrier to getting onto the Part III course, provided there is a satisfactory explanation as to why - my expeirence with the Faculty members (I'm an undergraduate studying Maths at Cambridge) is that they only really care for a person's mathematical ability.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and for the links that you provided! The 'excuse' for my high age is mainly that I was initially very uncertain about what I wanted to study, and it took me some time to settle with my current program.

Comment: I can't see your reason for your high age being a hinderence then.